# Git gui icon disappeared vs code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-gui

[image of my current vs Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQ6ro.png)
VSCode Version: 1.49.3
OS Version: 10.15.7

The git gui icon is missing. I have tried creating a new repo + git init. Also, I have tried to enable and disable git from settings nothing has worked. The cause of this is a button I accidentally pressed that removed it. IDK what the button said exactly... No updates recently. Any help with fixing this would be much appreciated!

I like using the git gui so would rather not switch back to the terminal for everything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right Click on Activity Bar and **Select/Check Source Control or keyboard shortcut (CTRL + SHFT + G on mac)**

Answer (score 6):

By right-clicking on the activity bar where the icons are and seeing if "Source Control" is checked I was able to get it back.

[gif of solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAIy2.gif)

Comment: Thanks your gif helped me fix the issue I was stuck on for a while.
For me, the explorer icon was showing the count of the git changed.
Then the way in gif you dragged the git source control I did that and it fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> in windows to get the git-gui icon

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer, in my case there was no "Source Control" Showing up in the Activity Bar. But thanks to the shortcut (CTRL + SHFT + G) the Source Control was highlighted, and i realized it somehow got into the Bottom Panel.

[Activity Bar showing no Source Control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGLDJ.png)

By drag and drop now i have the Source Control back on the Activity Bar.