# Explorer icon showing the git changes count in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

As shown in the below image the Explore icon has the badge showing the count of my git changes.
I don't know how this happened some how unexpectedly I did something and this behaviour started.
How do I fix it and get the default behaviour of the git icon showing the changes count?
[image]

Comment: what has changed in your `settings.json`, does it still happen after a restart, is it in all workspaces

Comment: Yes, it is happening after even restart, I even uninstalled the VS Code and reinstalled and it's still the same(I think it's persisting because I am logged in and settings are in sync).

Yes that's the issue that I can't find out what has changed in `settings.json`
Yes it's happening for all the workspaces.

Answer (score 1):

You accidentally moved the **SOURCE CONTROL** View to the Explorer bar.

Is this view not present in the SCM Bar?

I have tried to do it with the mouse but could not recreate. It created a new SCM icon in the Activity Bar with 1 view.

To move all the views to the default position execute command: **View: Reset View locations**

Answer (score 0):

That Explorer icon badge is supposed to show the number of **unsaved** files with changes - it doesn't show the number of git changes except coincidentally.

I don't think the Explorer unsaved files count badge can be turned off. You can change its color or opacity but that would affect all badges (like the scm badge).

Comment: Yes, that's right that Explorer icon badge is supposed to show the number of unsaved files with changes but that is the issue some how it is showing me the git changes count. And the git icon isn't showing any changes count as it should be.

Comment: Are you sure you do not have any unsaved files when the Explorer icon shows a count?  And is the `SCM: Count Badge` setting set to `all`?

Comment: Yes, I don't have any unsaved files. I have posted the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70579647/9355359) solution the way I was able to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64264204/9355359) answer the [GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAIy2.gif) attached in answer was able to help me to fix the issue.
I just dragged the `Source Control` to the sidebar and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

[Shadab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9355359/shadab)
I had the same issue.
I solved it for me in this steps:

- open Expolrer menu (three dots in top right corner)
- select option "Open editors"
- in Open editiors section save and close files

Here is helpfull screenshot
[image]